# css("position") returns undefined when window resize

Tags: jquery, css

I've got the following code to catch the browser resize event.

```
 window.onresize = function(){
 var style = $('#button-selection').position();
 if(style == "relative"){
 $("#button-section").css("position"," ");
 }else if(style == "fixed"){
    $("#button-section").css("position","relative");
 }              
 };


 window.onresize = function(){
            var style = $('#button-selection').css('position');
            if(style == "relative"){
                $("#button-section").css("position"," ");
            }else if(style == "fixed"){
                $("#button-section").css("position","relative");
            }               
        };
```

The style returns undefined. I'm running this when the document is ready. I tried using window ready but the result is the same. both the above methods return undefined!

Comment: 2nd part of script works for me as expected. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/haZfH/

Maybe you should check what css('position') actually outputs. Maybe the problem is on the css side.

Comment: I'll check on it! theoretically the second method should work!

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
var style = $('#button-selection').position();
```

to this:

```
var style = $('#button-selection').css('position');
```

[`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) is used to get the coordinates of the element.

#### From the docs:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

---

### Update:

Use `$(window).resize()` instead. i am having a test case scenario here: [**in this fiddle**.](http://jsfiddle.net/fty7C/)

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var style = $('button').css('position');
  if (style == "relative") {
    alert('relative');
  } else if (style == "fixed") {
    alert('fixed');
  }
});
```

Comment: I used that method but the result is the same!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri just updated the answer and added a fiddle link too. Check and see if that helps.

Comment: I used your method and it works, but there is a bug where it fires twice when i minimize or maximize the screen!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri Yup because both time `.resize()` happens.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery docs say .position() is:

> Description: Get the current coordinates of the first element in the
>   set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

you should use:

```
 var style = $('#button-selection').css('position');
```